# Creating nested comments in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.6

I have the following blog control

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $post = Blog::where('slugs', '=', $slug)->first();

    $vars['pageTitle'] = Config::get('site.pageTitle') . $post['title'];

    // The breadcrumbs... needs to be repopulated every page
    $vars['breadCrumbs'] = [[
        'url'   => action('SimpleController@index'),
        'title' => 'CovertDEV'
    ],[
        'url'   => action('BlogController@index'),
        'title' => 'Blog'
    ],[
        'url'   => route('blog_post', ['slug' => $slug]),
        'title' => $post['title']
    ]];

    $vars['blog'] = $post;

    $vars['comments'] = $post->Blog_comments->groupBy('comment_id');

    return view('blog', $vars);
}
```

And the following scary view for the comments

```
@php
function display_comments($main, $depth = "\t")
{
    foreach($main[0] as $mcomment)
    {
@endphp
                                <div class="media">
                                    <img class="m-3 avatar-sm rounded-1 border border-thick-1 shadow" src="../public/css/images/avatar-placeholder.png" alt="<?=$mcomment->firstname;?> <?=$mcomment->lastname;?>'s Avatar">
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h6 class="mt-0 p-1 lead m-0 border-bottom"><?=$mcomment->firstname;?> <?=$mcomment->lastname;?></h6>
                                          <div class="p-2">
                                            <p><?=$mcomment->comment;?></p>
                                        </div>
@php
        if(isset($main[$mcomment->id]))
        {
            display_child($main, $main[$mcomment->id], $depth);
        }
@endphp
                                    </div>
                                </div>
@php
    }
}

function display_child($main, $comment, $depth)
{
    foreach($comment as $ccomment)
    {
@endphp
                                        <div class="media">
                                            <img class="m-3 avatar-sm rounded-1 border border-thick-1 shadow" src="../public/css/images/avatar-placeholder.png" alt="<?=$ccomment->firstname;?> <?=$ccomment->lastname;?>'s Avatar">
                                            <div class="media-body">
                                                <h6 class="mt-0 p-1 lead m-0 border-bottom"><?=$ccomment->firstname;?> <?=$ccomment->lastname;?></h6>
                                                <div class="p-2">
                                                    <p><?=$ccomment->comment;?></p>
                                                </div>
@php
        if(isset($main[$ccomment->id]))
        {
            display_child($main, $main[$ccomment->id], $depth."\t");
        }
@endphp
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
@php

    }
}

display_comments($comments);

@endphp
```

That is as ugly as it gets. It generates how I want it, but that is ugly, terribly ugly.

[This is an image of the created nested comments](https://ibb.co/htiNdH)

What is the best way to make this work elegantly in the blade template? I tried extending the blade template thing according to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#extending-blade), but that didn't prove fruitful for me. I simply couldn't figure out how to do it.

With this, I can't call asset, or anything like that... those are already out of scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my solution I'm satisfied with. If anyone has a better solution, do feel free to suggest.

My Blog controller is the same, only thing that changed is my view. In my blog view (where I see those comments as a user):

`blog.blade.php`

```
@foreach($comments[0] as $comment)
<div class="media comment">
@if(!is_null($comment->users['avatar']))
    <img class="m-3 avatar-sm rounded-1 border border-thick-1 shadow" src="{{ asset( Config::get('site.asset_folder') . 'users/images/' . $comment->users['avatar']) }}" alt="{{ $comment->users['firstname'] }} {{ $comment->users['lastname'] }}'s Avatar">
@else
    <img class="m-3 avatar-sm rounded-1 border border-thick-1 shadow" src="{{ asset( Config::get('site.asset_folder') . 'css/images/avatar-placeholder.png') }}" alt="{{ $comment->users['firstname'] }} {{ $comment->users['lastname'] }}'s Avatar">
@endif
    <div class="media-body">
        <h6 class="mt-0 p-1 lead m-0 border-bottom">{{ $comment->users['firstname'] }} {{ $comment->users['lastname'] }}</h6>
          <div class="p-2">
            <p>{{ $comment->comment }}</p>
        </div>
@if(isset($comments[$comment->id]))
    @include('block.comments', ['comments' => $comments, 'parent_id' => $comment->id, 'depth' => 0])
@endif
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

And then, my `block/comments.blade.php`

```
@foreach($comments[$parent_id] as $comment)
@if($depth >= Config::get('site.max_nested'))
    </div>
</div>

@endif
<div class="media comment">
@if(!is_null($comment->users['avatar']))
    <img class="m-3 avatar-sm rounded-1 border border-thick-1 shadow" src="{{ asset( Config::get('site.asset_folder') . 'users/images/' . $comment->users['avatar']) }}" alt="{{ $comment->users['firstname'] }} {{ $comment->users['lastname'] }}'s Avatar">
@else
    <img class="m-3 avatar-sm rounded-1 border border-thick-1 shadow" src="{{ asset( Config::get('site.asset_folder') . 'css/images/avatar-placeholder.png') }}" alt="{{ $comment->users['firstname'] }} {{ $comment->users['lastname'] }}'s Avatar">
@endif
    <div class="media-body">
        <h6 class="mt-0 p-1 lead m-0 border-bottom">{{ $comment->users['firstname'] }} {{ $comment->users['lastname'] }}</h6>
        <div class="p-2">
            <p>{{ $comment->comment }}</p>
        </div>
@if(isset($comments[$comment->id]))
    @include('block.comments', ['comments' => $comments, 'parent_id' => $comment->id, 'depth' => $depth + 1])
@endif
@if($depth < Config::get('site.max_nested'))
    </div>
</div>
@endif
@endforeach
```

And then I have a config file `site` in the config folder with the following contents

```
return [
    // We define the max depth for the nested comments
    // You could obviously define this value in database and be retrieving it from there
    'max_nested'    => 3,
];
```

The way my `$comments` array is set-up, the parent comments are always going to be in `$comments[0]` while the child comments would be in `$comments[$parent_id]`

I think that's fairly simple yet effectively functional!